# What TERM types are still in common usage?

Tags: terminal, tty

I want to support 95% of terminals on *modern* desktop machines (and terminal emulators on phones).

Would supporting:

- xterm
- xterm-256color
- linux

be sufficient?

If not, which am I missing and where are they used?

Comment: `screen` is used by both GNU `screen` and `tmux` (having said that, my `tmux` seems to work better with `TERM` set to `rxvt`).

Comment: Have you looked at the `curses` library, or other libraries to do this. They will take care of the abstraction for you.